# Keep desired data and remove unwanted one

Tags: awk, delete-row

I have a large file containing thousands of rows and columns, I want to keep only **0, 1, -1, 2** from **column 2 onwards** and want to get rid of all other digits (*6|6, 3|3, 4|4,7|7, e.t.c.*).

**Input:**

```
1 55 -1 6|6 0 0 -1 1 2 0

1 56 -1 0 1 0 1 -1 -1 2 0 

1 63 3|3 -1 0 0 1 -1 -1 2

1 73 -1 2 0 1 -1 -1 -1 0 

1 75 -1 0 0 0 7|7 -1 -1 4|4 -1

1 80 -1 0 0 0 -1 5|5 -1 0 0 

1 83 -1 1 1 0 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

**Output:**

```
1 56 -1 0 1 0 1 -1 -1 2 0 

1 73 -1 2 0 1 -1 -1 -1 0 

1 83 -1 1 1 0 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

I have tried various options (**sed, awk, grep**) but unfortunately unable to fix this problem, Your kind help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `tried various options` please add some of them to question.. otherwise it might come across as no effort shown (hover mouse over the downvote button to see why that is important)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This following simple `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '!/[0-9]+\|[0-9]+/'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1 56 -1 0 1 0 1 -1 -1 2 0
1 73 -1 2 0 1 -1 -1 -1 0
1 83 -1 1 1 0 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

***Explanation:*** `!/[0-9]+\|[0-9]+/` checking condition here if a line is NOT having ***digit|(pipe)digit*** if not that condition is TRUE then print that line(`awk` works on method of condition and then action, so here when condition is TRUE I am not mentioning any action so default action print of current line will happen.)

***Solution 2nd:*** solution with `sed` too here:

```
sed -n -E '/[0-9]+\|[0-9]+/d;p'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** 
`-n`: Stops the printing for `sed` until we explicitly mention to print any line by `p` option.
`-E`: is used for:

> ```
>    -e script, --expression=script
>           add the script to the commands to be executed
> ```

`/[0-9]+\|[0-9]+/d`: is a regex where I am checking here if a line has ***digit|digit*** then using `d` option to delete/skip that line.
`p`: In case previous condition is NOT satisfied in any line then print the line since it will not have ***digit|digit*** in that line.

Answer (score 3):

You would also get the same output by doing:

```
grep -v '|' input_file
```

It works in your specific example, but is not as robust as the `awk` solution.

Comment: Perfect, It worked, it was simple and i was getting into complexities for no reason. Highly appreciated